# How can I copy $BASHPID in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, network-namespaces

I have a network namespace and I want to run command with this netns bash pid, how can I do it in bash script?
Code example:

```
sudo ip netns add ns1 #this is my network namespace

#In separate shell I have to run following commands
sudo ip netns exec ns1 bash
echo $BASHPID #I want to use this bash pid in the next command 

sudo iw phy phy0 set netns xxxx # xxxx is the example of bash pid
```

Is it possible to run this in one bash script? When I try to do it by using command to open another shell and save bash pid as a variable it doesn't work.

Comment: What about using the output from `ip netns pids ns1`?

Comment: I don't want to get processes id from netns ns1. I want to use ns1 $BASHPID in the command showed above in my script.

Comment: It's the same thing as far as my tests show

Comment: But when I execute this command bash returns nothing.

Comment: The command `sudo ip netns exec ns1 bash` waits for `bash` to complete. It won't complete until you Ctrl/D or `exit` from the session it creates

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to save $BASHPID to variable and use it in bash script. When I tried make script to open another terminal and use sudo ip netns exec ns1 bash and save $BASHPID to variable it wasn't work.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Can you explain in your question what you want to achieve? (Forget about `$BASHPID`; what's the end goal?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understood your question, however, I'll do my best, hope it helps.

1. Why do not you use `$BASHPID` instead of `xxx` in your code :

   ```bsh
   sudo iw phy phy0 set netns "$BASHPID"
   ```
2. You can store it to a variable:

   ```bsh
   YourVariable=$BASHPID
   ```

   And then use the variable same as what I mentioned in number 1:

   ```bsh
   sudo iw phy phy0 set netns "$YourVariable"
   ```
3. You can store it to a file:

   ```bsh
   echo "$BASHPID" > YourFile
   ```

   It creates a new file named YourFile, with the bash pid within.

   You can later on read it and use it for a new variable :

   ```bsh
   YourVariable=$(cat YourFile)
   ```

   Note that you should be in the same directory as `YourFile` or use the full directory of `YourFile`.

   Finally, you can use `YourVariable` similarly as mentioned in number 2.

   ```bsh
   sudo iw phy phy0 set netns "$YourVariable"
   ```